# PlatformException (PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null))

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

In my flutter project I am getting exception whenever I am trying to pickup an image either from Camera or Gallery using the image_picker plugin of flutter.
If I try to choose the camera or gallery even after restarting the app.

[image]

Below are the dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc: ^8.1.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0
  pie_chart: ^5.3.2
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.2.46


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  survey_kit: ^0.1.1
  splash_screen_view: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2
```

Comment: This issue only occurs when running on the emulator.
You won't get this error when you try it on a real device.

Comment: This issue is both on the emulator and real device

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you start ImagePicker more than once, put a logline before ImagePicker().pickImage and you should see if it gets called again before you finished the first one.